# Insert data into tables that have foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to insert data into tables that have foreign key for related table.

I am using Rails and MySQL. I have posts table and post_bodies table. I want to insert data into the tables with "accepts_nested_attributes_for".

The table structure is the below.

When I insert data from Post model, error says "you need default value for post_body_id(FK)". So I try to set data for post_body_id but error says "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails". I am wondering how I can insert data into tables.

Tables

```
◼️posts table
id(PK)
title
post_body_id(FK)


◼️post_body_tables
id(PK)
body
post_id(FK)
```

Model

```
◼️Post
has_one :post_body
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_body, allow_destroy: true

◼️post_body
belongs_to :post_id
```

Controller

```
◼️PostController
  def post_params
    params.permit(
                    :title,
                    :post_body_id,
                    :post_body_attributes => [:id, :post_id, :body, :_destroy]
                  )
  end
```

Comment: this is not a good approach you should have only post_id in body table there is no need to add post_body_id in post table @ken

Comment: I will search for data from posts table and from post_bodies table. In that case, I don't need FK in both tables? I mean how about performance to search for data if there is no FK. I am not sure about that.

Comment: You can search data just go through the some basic database course.

Comment: it is strange have belongs_to :post_id in your post_body table. is that a typo mistake?

Comment: You're mixing up foreign keys and indexes. For search you need indexes

Comment: In the case, I guess I don't need post_body_id(FK) in posts table rather than post_id(FK) in post_bodies table. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Remove post_body_id from post model.